# Cloud 9 can't retrieve class with simple javascript code?

Tags: javascript, cloud9-ide, getelementsbyclassname

On my current workspace site, ( run `from cloud 9 IDE` )I have two very simple blocks of code:

**HTML**

```
<span class="subject"> Github </span>
<div class="content">
    <hr>
    <span class="lSubj" style="color: navy;"> <a href="link"> Link </a> </span>
    <pre><div class="gitContent">Filler Text</div></pre>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function gitFire(){
    var gits = document.getElementsByClassName("gitContent");
    for( var i = 0; i < gits.length; i ++ )
    {
        var element = gits[i];
        alert( element.innerHTML );
    }
}

document.onload += gitFire();
```

**CLOUD 9 space Link:** https://c9.io/lemony_andrew/leandrew/workspace/test.html

**Js Fiddle Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/T3jkp/1/

1. No errors in debug console.
2. Cloud 9 isn't finding classes, but jsfiddle does.
3. Cloud 9  **Is** executing the code. I believe the problem is with: **getElementsByClassName**
4. Changing `document.onload += gitFire;` to `document.onload = gitFire;` does not effect the outcome.

I think it may be cloud 9's fault, but I have never had any problems like this before. Why else could it possibly work on jsfiddle and not my workspace?

Answer (score 0):

You execute `gitFire` immediately instead of attaching a onload handler. It works on JSFiddle because they are always waiting for the DOM to be loaded before executing scripts.

```
document.onload = gitFire;
```

Comment: `document.onload += gitFire();` and `document.onload = gitFire;` do exactly the same thing. ( at least in the outcome ). Thanks for your input.

Comment: Wait!! Explain yourself a little more please, I just tried something in relation to your answer: `window.onload = function(){` made the script work.. `window.onload = function(){` but I changed it to work like this: `window.onload = function(){ window.onload + gitFire(); };` NOW, this works only using window. Why not document?

Comment: I have no clue, document.onload doesn't get executed in Firefox. The best solution however is `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", gitFire);`; it works in all modern browsers.

Comment: Hey! That worked even better, although it doesn't explain what's going on, it's a solution. You should change your answer to that and I'll except it! Thank you.